# WiX bootstrapper: How to access execution path

Tags: c#, wpf, wix

I am trying to access the path of my Setup.exe from within my bootstrapper. But using `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` always returns the temp path where the executable seems to be unpacked. How can I get i.e. "c:\downloads" when my Setup.exe was started from there?

Comment: Why do you need it? There might be a better way to achieve your overall goal if you can tell us what it is.

Comment: I needed this to load a reseller file that comes along with the setup.exe, containing the name of the reseller, product name and so on... It needs to allow quick replacement of the file by another reseller file without building the setup again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Application.StartupPath;
```

This gives you the path of the exe, which started the program:

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, this works. I was only aware of the `Assembly` classes to get the application execution path. Lesson learned. :-)